# Difference between the syntax

Tags: passive-voice

Which one of the following sentences will be passive voice of "I was sanctioned the loan by the office".

The office sanctioned loan to me.

The office sanctioned me the loan.

What differences are created because of the above two constructs as both give same meaning and seems equally correct. Please illustrate.

Comment: In standard English, **sanctioned** does not take an indirect object (sanctioned *me* the loan), at least  I've never heard it or seen it used in that manner. Neither do **approved** or **authorized**. You could change it to **granted** or **issued**

Answer (score 2):

> The bank issued me the loan.
>
> The bank issued the loan to me.

*The loan was issued to me by the bank.*

*I was issued the loan by the bank.*

You could read about so-called "[ditransitive verbs](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/ditransitive-english-verbs/)" and passive constructions.